# Why would an immediately destroyed shared pointer leak memory?

Tags: c++, boost-asio, smart-pointers

Is there a memory leak here?

```
class myclass : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<myclass>{
//...
    void broadcast(const char *buf){
    broadcast(new std::string(buf));
    }

    void broadcast(std::string *buf){
    boost::shared_ptr<std::string> msg(buf);
    }
//...
};
```

(This is the stripped down version that still shows the problem - normally I do real work in that second `broadcast` call!)
My assumption was that the first call gets some memory, then because I do nothing with the smart pointer the second call would immediately delete it. Simple? But, when I run my program, the memory increases over time, in jumps. Yet when I comment out the only call in the program to broadcast(), it does not!

The ps output for the version without `broadcast()`:

```
 %CPU  %MEM     VSZ    RSS  TIME
 3.2   0.0     158068  1988 0:00 
 3.3   0.0     158068  1988 0:25  (12 mins later)
```

With the call to `broadcast()` (on Ubuntu 10.04, g++ 4.4, boost 1.40)

```
 %CPU  %MEM     VSZ    RSS  TIME
 1.0    0.0    158068  1980 0:00
 3.3    0.0    158068  1988 0:04  (2 mins)
 3.4    0.0    223604  1996 0:06  (3.5 mins)
 3.3    0.0    223604  2000 0:09
 3.1    0.0    223604  2000 2:21  (82 mins)
 3.1    0.0    223604  2000 3:50  (120 mins)
```

(Seeing that jump at around 3 minutes is reproducible in the few times I've tried so far.)

With the call to `broadcast()` (on Centos 5.6, g++ 4.1, boost 1.41)

```
 %CPU  %MEM     VSZ    RSS  TIME
 0.0    0.0     51224  1744 0:00
 0.0    0.0     51224  1744 0:00  (30s)
 1.1    0.0    182296  1776 0:02  (3.5 mins)
 0.7    0.0    182296  1776 0:03
 0.7    0.0    182296  1776 0:09  (20 mins)
 0.7    0.0    247832  1788 0:14  (34 mins)
 0.7    0.0    247832  1788 0:17
 0.7    0.0    247832  1788 0:24  (55 mins)
 0.7    0.0    247832  1788 0:36  (71 mins)
```

Here is how `broadcast()` is being called (from a boost::asio timer) and now I'm wondering if it could matter:

```
void callback(){
//...
timer.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(20));
//...
char buf[512];
sprintf(buf,"...");
broadcast(buf);
timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&myclass::callback, shared_from_this() ));
//...
}
```

(callback is in the same class as the broadcast function)

I have 4 of these timers going, and my `io_service.run()` is being called by a pool of 3 threads. My 20ms time-out means each timer calls `broadcast()` 50 times/second. I set the expiry at the start of my function, and run the timer near the end. The elided code is not doing that much; outputting debug info to std::cout is perhaps the most CPU-intensive job. I suppose it may be possible the timer triggers immediately sometimes; but, still, I cannot see how that would be a problem, let alone cause a memory leak.

(The program runs fine, by the way, even when doing its full tasks; I only got suspicious when I noticed the memory usage reported by ps had jumped up.)

**UPDATE:** Thanks for the answers and comments. I can add that I left the program running on each system for another couple of hours and memory usage did not increase any further. (I was also ready to dismiss this as a one-off heap restructuring or something, when the Centos version jumped for a second time.) Anyway, it is good to know that my understanding of smart pointers is still sound, and that there is no weird corner case with threading that I need to be concerned about.

Comment: 1) Your code sample doesn't compile. 2) After I [fixed it](http://ideone.com/FCPHf), I ran it under valgrind. It doesn't leak.

Comment: I suspect you're seeing the effects of heap management, rather than leaking (e.g. fragmentation and such). Sometimes the heap manager might give you a new chunk of RAM rather than reuse an existing one for perf considerations, and that behavior is unspecified. If you want to really check for such things use a debugging allocator (MSVC++ comes with one, for GCC you can do as Rob did and use Valgrind)

Comment: If the code you shown is the only thing the program does it might be a problem. However, you are probably doing a lot of other things as well and that could easily account for the difference.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for checking in valgrind. Regarding not compiling, I changed my code snippet to show that the functions are part of the same class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a leak, you allocate a `std::string` (20 bytes, more or less) 50 times per second.
in 1 hour you should have been allocated ... 3600*50*20 = 3,4MBytes.

Nothing to do with th 64K you see, that's probably due to the way the system allocate the memory to the process, that `new` sub-allocates to the variables.

The system, when something is deleted, needs to "garbage collect it" placing it back into the available memory chain for further allocations.
But since this takes time, most of the systems don't do this operation until the released memory goes over certain amounts, so that a "repack" can be done.

Answer (score 1):

Well, what happens here is probably not that your program is leaking, but that for some reason the system memory allocator decided to keep another 64 kB page around for your application. If there was a constant memory leak at that point, at 50 Hz rate, that would have a much more dramatic effect!

Exactly why that is done after 3 minutes I don't know (I am not an expert in that area), but I would guess that there are some heuristics and statistics involved. Or, it could simply be that the heap has gotten fragmented.

Another thing that may have happened is that the messages you are holding in the buffer become longer over time :)